# how to remove part of text from the end to start by a symbol?

Tags: python

i have this text in Python

`C:\A\BB\CD\project\venv\dds\Movies\A1124746E`

i want to remove all the text after the last `\` from end to start,

so that the text end up like this `A1124746E`.

how can i achieve this?

Comment: do you want just last elements after '\'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'C:\A\BB\CD\project\venv\dds\Movies\A1124746E'.split('\\')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to get the substring after the last '\':

```
 def getLastString(text):
        return text[text.rfind('\\') + 1:]
```